# How do I make this javascript reusable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that I use many times. Here's the code and an example use:

```
$('.close-cookie-notice').click(function (e) {

    // make this reusable
    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
        e.returnValue = false;
    }
    // end of reusable code
    $('#site-cookie-notice').slideUp();
});
```

The code I need to reuse is between the comments. I would like this to reside in its own function but am not sure how to deal with the passing of the event (e).

Anyone help?

Comment: just pass it like any other parameter

Comment: You don't need to do this, jQuery already normalizes events across browsers for you and shims `preventDefault` in older browsers.

Comment: To make source code reusable, reduce the assumptions that the source makes.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - I had an instant (about 12 months ago), where jquery wasn't handling this and causing the code to crash in IE8. This code fixed it. It would be good to remove but I'm wary.

Comment: @dotnetnoob what version of jQuery? If you can reproduce this you should file a bug report. jQuery is an open source community project and any input you have that may fix a bug could really help.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - I'm currently using 1.9.2, so its likely that the version would have been 1.5/1.6 ish

Comment: @dotnetnoob you can safely remove that code and just call `preventDefault` in a normalized way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function myspecialfunction(e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        e.returnValue = false;
    }
}
```

Used as:

```
$('.close-cookie-notice').click(function (e) {
    myspecialfunction(e);
    $('#site-cookie-notice').slideUp();
});
```